# Hello guys i have a problem in bitwise a binary value in c#

Tags: c#

I wrote a program that takes a word and then converts it into a binary value and makes shifts to the right or the left.
This is the code:

```cpp
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace mysecondproject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pls enter a word: ");
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(word);
            
            string wordinbinary = "";
            foreach (byte b in byteArray)
            {
                wordinbinary  = Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
                Console.Write(wordinbinary);
            }

            long longwordinbinary = Convert.ToInt64(wordinbinary);
            Console.WriteLine(longwordinbinary);
            string binaryRepresentation2 = "";
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.Write("pls enter the key: ");
            int key = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            long shiftedValue = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("pls choose do you want to shift the word to the left or to the right. left / right");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer == "left")
            {
                shiftedValue = longwordinbinary << key;
                binaryRepresentation2 = Convert.ToString(shiftedValue, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            }
            else if (answer == "right")
            {
                shiftedValue = longwordinbinary >> key;
                binaryRepresentation2 = Convert.ToString(shiftedValue, 2).PadRight(8, '0');
            }

            
            Console.WriteLine(binaryRepresentation2);
```

When trying to bitwise a binary value to the left or to the right I am not getting the right result.

*For example:*
Input:

```
0111001001101111011000110110101101100101011101001110100
```

Output:

```
10000111100000101010000000
```

Expected Ouput:

```
0011011110110001101101011011001010111010011101000111010
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that if you want to shift or rotate the characters inside a word. Some characters are encoded with one byte, some with two and with even more in UTF-8. Also, this will convert one character to another. (If this is what you wanted, then please explain with a concrete example what word was entered, which result you expected and which result you got instead.)

Convert the string to a `char` array instead:

```cs
char[] charArr = word.ToCharArray();
```

Now, you can create a new array of chars with the shifted or rotated characters.

You can then convert the result back to a string with:

```cs
string result = new String(resultCharArr);
```

Comment: Hi Olivier i fixed what you said and added something because i saw that i was only printing the value of wordinbinary so the result is only the last bits right now i have a different problem i am getting "Value was either too large or too small for an Int64." after getting the binary value how i can fix it do you any ideas? this is the code:

`string wordinbinary = ""; foreach (byte b in charArr) { wordinbinary += Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'); } Console.Write(wordinbinary); long longwordinbinary = Convert.ToInt64(wordinbinary);`

Comment: Note that `Int64` has 8 bytes. If the word is longer than that, you could use a [BitArray Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray). It has `LeftShift` and `RightShift` methods and can be of any length.